# Oracle: Ordering/sorting records based on the difference value of a column data in different rows of same table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table `error_event_table`, with 3 columns:

```
eventtime timestamp;
url varchar2(1024);
errorcount number(30);
```

the table is having more than 3 million data, I need to find the top n(100) URL's based on the difference of errorcount column value for a given start time and endtime.
for ex: table data as below

```
eventtime           | url      |errorcount
2018-01-29 10:20:00 | url1.com | 950
2018-01-29 10:25:00 | url1.com | 1000
2018-01-29 10:20:00 | url2.com | 100
2018-01-29 10:25:00 | url2.com | 400
2018-01-29 10:25:00 | url3.com | 500
2018-01-29 10:10:00 | url35.com | 500
```

when startTime=2018-01-29 10:20:00 and endTime= 2018-01-29 10:25:00  are passed as inputs to the query, the expected output is:

```
eventtime           | url      |errorcount

2018-01-29 10:25:00 | url3.com | 500
2018-01-29 10:25:00 | url2.com | 400
2018-01-29 10:20:00 | url2.com | 100
2018-01-29 10:25:00 | url1.com | 1000
2018-01-29 10:20:00 | url1.com | 950
```

the query should order the records based on the difference of errorcount number at given start time and end time (inputs for the query) descending and limit the results to top 100. To say in other way, the query should find the top 100 URL's with the max difference at end time and start time, and result the corresponding URL's records at both start time and end time.

it is possible that an URL exists only at end time and not at start time, in that case the start time errorcount should be taken as 0. similarly an URL might exists only at start time in which case the diff will be negative number and i don't want these -ve diff records in my results.

I have tried two approaches and not able to get the proper approach to procede furthur.

Approach 1: Using Group By

```
SELECT url, 
       Max(eventtime), 
       Max(errorcount) 
FROM   error_event_table 
WHERE  eventtime IN ( To_date(:startTime, 'yyyymmddHH24MISS'), 
                      To_date(:endTime, 'yyyymmddHH24MISS') 
                           ) 
GROUP  BY url 
ORDER  BY Max(errorcount)DESC;
```

Approch 2: Using Self Join

```
SELECT t2.url                            eurl, 
       t1.url                            surl, 
       t2.eventtime                      endtime, 
       t1.eventtime                      starttime, 
       ( t2.errorcount - t1.errorcount ) diff 
FROM   error_event_table t1, 
       error_event_table t2 
WHERE  ( t1.eventtime = To_date(:startTime, 'yyyymmddHH24MISS') 
          OR t2.eventtime = To_date(:endTime, 'yyyymmddHH24MISS') ) 
       AND t2.url (+) = t1.url 
ORDER  BY ( t2.errorcount - t1.errorcount ) DESC
```

Pls provides inputs on how to approach for solving this problem..

Comment: `based on the difference of errorcount number` explain how you want  calculate that?  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated the question with sample expected output

Comment: Can you include the difference you mention on the sample data? Right now looks like is just `order by errorcount desc` what if instead `url1=500` where `url1 = 50`, what result you would get?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza , it is not just order by errorcount. for ex: if url1=1000 at end point and url1=950 at start point, then the diff is 50, so these 2 records should come at the bottom of result set as the diff is the least among the others.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (error_count - 
        lag(error_count, 1, 0) over (partition by url order by eventtime)
       ) as diff
from t
where <date conditions here>
order by diff desc;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the URLs with the maximums, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by url order by diff desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (error_count - 
                    lag(error_count, 1, 0) over (partition by url order by eventtime)
                   ) as diff
            from t
            where <date conditions here>
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 100
order by diff desc;
```

Comment: probably `order by url, diff`

Comment: it did not work for the case where an URL exist only at start time , then the difference is actually negative number, but it is returning a positive number with this query..

Comment: @Sekhar . . . Do error counts increase or decrease?  This assumes that they increase.  If they decrease then do the subtraction in the other order.  The third argument to `lag()` defines the default value of `0`, so it is really hard to see how the expression would produce a negative number or `NULL`.

Comment: it worked fine for the records at the end time value, but it did not work as expected for start time records because this query trying to find the difference between the errorcount value at start time value record also with it's previous , but there is no previous record exists, so the diff is coming same as the value of errorcount, so it is coming in top of the records order. For example: URL3 has error count 400 at start point and 100 at end point, the diff is -300, in this case i want URL3 to be completely filtered out from the results (as it is -ve difference between end and start point)

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. the error count can increase or decrease, both possible .. also some times records exists for an URL only at either start point or end point